# On ansible-awx, Unable to create a System Administrator after deleting the only one existing

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I created an account on Ansible-AWX with username-'admin' with *System Administrator* privileges.
I made 'admin' as *Normal User*. So my AWX instance does not have any System Admin . Hence I can not give back 'admin' System Admin permissions.
How can i create a new system admin or give 'admin' the same privileges ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i create a new system admin or give 'admin' the same privileges ?

You can use the same [Django objects that they use](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/2.1.2/installer/roles/kubernetes/tasks/main.yml#L178), and ask it to create another superuser on your behalf:

```sh
awx-manage shell <<'EOF'
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser('admin-username', 'email@example.com',
                              'sooper-secret-password')
EOF
```